# Upload your IPA file to internal server using Fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

Is it possible to use *fastlane* to upload beta-testingIPA to your internal server?

Let's say you are using share point and you want to upload your IPA at share point.

Does *fastlane* has any feature like this?

I saw couple of article where we can upload IPA to AWS. So hoping we can do similar if you configure *fastlane* for any other server URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this plugin I have developed.
https://github.com/MaxToyberman/fastlane-plugin-upload-to-server

here is an example of how to use it, just run it after gym:

```
gym(scheme: "MyApp")
upload_to_server(
  endPoint: 'your endpoint here',
  multipartPayload: {
  // any parameters can be added here  
  :iosVersionNumber => options[:version]
  },
  headers:{

  }
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to analyze/parse the server-response? (response body and http status code)

Comment: @Mehlyfication it should be printed

Comment: Hi @MaximToyberman, how I can set an header with `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 0):

I think Fastlane only provides Beta deployment to one of the supporting beta testing services namely Testflight,Fabric Beta, HockeyApp and TestFairy. You could refer this links for more info [Fastlane Docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/)

Comment: Yes. Correct but you can also upload your beta testing file to AWS. As it is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157644/uploading-to-s3-with-fastlane. So I am looking something like it where we can configure some  env and make it work for internal server as well. Thanks.